# When can we upgrade $k$-space definitions under a local Hausdorff condition?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms

There are a number of differing definitions of a compactly generated space, also known as a "$k$-space."  Following the notation from [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactly_generated_space#Definitions), we define a topological space $X$ to be

> $CG_1$ if $X$ is coherent with its compact subspaces, i.e., a subset $A\subseteq X$ is closed (resp. open) if and only if its intersection $A\cap K$ is closed (open) for each compact $K\subseteq X$

> $CG_2$ if $X$ is determined by the family of continuous maps from compact Hausdorff spaces into $X$, i.e., $A\subseteq X$ is closed if and only if $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed in $Z$ for every continuous map $f\colon Z\to X$ from a compact Hausdorff space $Z$ into $X$.

> $CG_3$ if $X$ is coherent with its compact Hausdorff subspaces.

From the definitions we clearly always have $$CG_3\implies CG_2\implies CG_1,$$ and a search of [$\pi$-Base](https://topology.pi-base.org/) yields plenty of examples showing the implications are strict.  On the other hand, for Hausdorff spaces all three definitions coincide.

---

The main purpose of this question is to record, for the benefit of automated deductions in $\pi$-Base, that under a local Hausdorff condition (i.e., every point has a Hausdorff neighborhood), we have the implications

> $$\text{Locally Hausdorff} + \text{Locally Compact} \implies CG_3,\tag{1}$$
> $$\text{Locally Hausdorff} +CG_2\implies CG_3,\tag{2}$$

where local compactness means every point has a neighborhood basis of compact neighborhoods.
We also want to provide a counter-example to establish that locally Hausdorff and $CG_1$ are not sufficient to conclude $CG_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both (1) and (2) it is helpful to observe that if a family of subsets $\mathcal A\subseteq \mathcal P(X)$ is coherent for a topology on $X$, then every family $\mathcal B\subseteq \mathcal P(X)$ such that each $A\in \mathcal A$ is a subset of some $B\in \mathcal B$, is also coherent for $X$.  Moreover, every open cover $\mathcal U$ of $X$ is coherent, since if $A\cap U$ is open in $U\in\mathcal U$, then $A\cap U$ is open in $X$, so that $A=\bigcup_{U\in\mathcal U} A\cap U$ is open.

---

Implication (1) follows immediately from the fact that if $X$ is locally compact and locally Hausdorff, then every point has a neighborhood basis of compact Hausdorff sets.  Since the family of interiors of such neighborhoods is an open cover of $X$, it is coherent.  Since each interior is contained in a compact Hausdorff subset, the family of compact Hausdorff subsets of $X$ is also coherent.  Therefore $X$ is $CG_3$.

---

To prove (2), suppose $X$ is $CG_2$ and locally Hausdorff, and $A\subseteq X$, with $A\cap K$ closed in $K$ for each compact Hausdorff $K\subseteq X$.  We must show that $A$ is closed in $X$.

To this end, let $f\colon Z\to X$ be a map from a compact Hausdorff $Z$.  Let $\mathcal U$ be the family of all Hausdorff open subsets of $X$, which by definition cover $X$.  Thus $\{f^{-1}(U)\mid U\in \mathcal U\}$ covers $Z$.  By regularity, the family $$\mathcal V=\{V\subseteq Z\mid V\text{ is open, } \exists U\in \mathcal U\, \overline{V}\subseteq f^{-1}(U)\}$$
also covers $Z$, and so as an open cover is coherent with the topology on $Z$.  A fortiori the family of supersets $\mathcal W=\{f^{-1}(f(\overline{V}))\mid V\in \mathcal V\}$ is also coherent.

But for $V\in \mathcal V$, $f(\overline{V})$ is compact, and Hausdorff (as it lies in some $U\in\mathcal U$), whereby $A\cap f(\overline{V})$ is closed in $f(\overline{V})$.  Thus $f^{-1}(A)\cap f^{-1}(f(\overline{V}))$ is closed in  $f^{-1}(f(\overline{V}))$, hence by the coherence of $\mathcal W$, $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed in $Z$.  Since $f$ and $Z$ were arbitrary, by $CG_2$ we conclude $A$ is closed in $X$, as desired.

---

Finally, for the fact that $CG_1$ and locally Hausdorff do not imply $CG_2$, we have a counter-example in the [one point-compactification $X^* $ of the Arens-Fort space $X$.](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000165)

$X^* $ is locally Hausdorff, since $X$ is Hausdorff, and $\infty$ has $X^* \backslash\{(0,0)\}$ as a Hausdorff neighborhood (note this neighborhood is homeomorphic to $\omega+1$).  $X^* $ is also  $CG_1$ since it is compact, but [it is not $CG_2$](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000165/properties/P000141).

Comment: Very nicely explained!  Thank you.